# Memory leak with keyword 'create_fence' when imeplementing ios game on top of spritekit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

When I run Leaks profiling on my ios game, it has large amount of memory leaks detection with information as below:

[image]

My IOS game is built upon Spritekit framework in Swift language. I'm new to profiling IOS project, could anyone give me some idea where the problem could be and how to pinpoint it? Thanks a lot.

**p.s.** I've add code as below for testing whether there's any SKNode that has been generated and never `removeFromParent` which might cause memory leak, but from the result, the number of children element in the scene is only fluctuating between a fixed number, thus this is not where the problem resides in.

```
var count = 0
scene.enumerateChildNodesWithName("*") {
    node, stop in
    count += 1
    if (node is SKSpriteNode) {
        let sprite = node as! SKSpriteNode
        forEachSprite(sprite: sprite)
    }
}
print("memory_leak_detect_1=[\(count)]")

# Output
memory_leak_detect_1=[8]
memory_leak_detect_1=[8]
memory_leak_detect_1=[13]
memory_leak_detect_1=[4]
memory_leak_detect_1=[13]
memory_leak_detect_1=[4]
memory_leak_detect_1=[8]
memory_leak_detect_1=[7]
memory_leak_detect_1=[8]
memory_leak_detect_1=[9]
memory_leak_detect_1=[8]
memory_leak_detect_1=[13]
memory_leak_detect_1=[4]
memory_leak_detect_1=[7]
```

Comment: You are allocating an object and not releasing it somehow, where is the source code?

Comment: It seems like what causes memory leak, but in all the trace information in the figure, there's no footpath that could trace back to my code. All seems to related with Spritekit framework. Do you know where I could find it? @MoDJ

Comment: In the allocations instrument (the row above leaks), can you show us the persistent# from highest to lowest. Thats a good way to determine the type of leak.